# highcharts exporting - Java approach, app-convert.properties

Tags: highcharts

In the export server can you please let me know why the file app-convert.properties is embedded in the highcharts-export-convert.jar?

Every time a config change has to be done the export server has to be repackaged and deployed.
Instead if this file can be moved to the resources directory of highcharts-export-web then when the war is deployed the properties file will be available under WEB-INF/classes and the spring framework can still read the properties.

Once this change is done all you have to do is make changes to the properties and restart Tomcat or whichever app server you are running and the changes are automatically picked up.

I have tried this and it works well. To get this working in jetty some changes will have to be made to pom.xml.

Please let me know if you can make this change to the export server.

Comment: Can someone from Highcharts please comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your point. It wasn´t a very elegant solution. The main reason for having the property file in the highcharts-export-convert module was to make it possible to run the module without the 'web module'

I adjusted the spring-convert.xml file so it's now possible to override the property file from the highcharts-export-web module.

Place your app-convert.properties file in /WEB-INF/spring/ and the properties will be picked up by Spring.

See also this [commit](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/7053f0c60fd99a488f3ec2cea1bd5a65d1d4499b)

Comment: Actually moving it under WEB-INF/classes is sufficient, Spring will be able to access it since it is under the classpath. Just like you have log4j.properties, you can move the app-convert.properties under WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: I know, but I like to have it all gathered at one place.